# Acessing server files from client directory and the other way using create-react-app and babel-node

Tags: node.js, babeljs, create-react-app, babel-cli, babel-node

I have an ejected create-react-app client application and a server side application in the same bundle in a Windows 10 environment.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
app
 |--------- server.js
 |--------- package.json
 |--------- start-client.js
 |--------- start-server.js
 |
 |------ client
             |---- config
             |---- public
             |---- scripts
             |---- src
                     |---- components
                     |---- common <== Common files for both server and client
                     |--- etc...
```

As pointed out above, there are common files that needs to be used by server and client, and here is where my problem starts. These common files are `.js` (common routines) and `.json` (language files) files that needs to be imported by modules on server and client pieces of the solution.

If I put my common files just below server (app/common), my client complains that it cannot import it, as it goes outside the `app/client/src` directory:

```
Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../../../common/common which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

If I put the files on the client directory structure (app/client/src/common), I get the following error when running the server (`npm run server` that turns into `babel-node start-server.js`)

```
D:\DEV\app\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:328
        throw e;
        ^

Error: Using `babel-preset-react-app` requires that you specify `NODE_ENV` or `BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are "development", "test", and "production". Instead, received: undefined. (While processing preset: "D:\\9. DEV\\WORKSPACE\\momejected\\client\\node_modules\\babel-preset-react-app\\index.js")
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\DEV\app\client\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\index.js:47:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\DEV\app\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at D:\DEV\app\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:296:17
    at Array.map (native)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (D:\DEV\app\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:275:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (D:\DEV\app\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (D:\DEV\app\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (D:\DEV\app\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
    at compile (D:\DEV\app\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:103:45)
```

Here is the `package.json` for the server:

```
{
  "name": "appserver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"babel-node start-server\" \"babel-node start-client\"",
    "server": "nodemon --exec \"babel-node start-server.js\"",
    "client": "nodemon --exec \"babel-node start-client.js\"",
    "schema": "\"babel-node scripts/update-client-schema.js\"",
    "mongoose": "\"cd models && babel-node build-mongoose-schemas.js\"",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "express-graphql": "^0.6.6",
    "graphql": "^0.10.3",
    "graphql-relay": "^0.5.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.11.1",
    "morgan": "^1.8.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "validator": "^9.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.9.0",
    "fs-extra": "^4.0.1",
    "node-fetch": "^1.7.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "stage-0",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-runtime"
    ]
  }
}
```

Questions:

a) Where should I put my common files. On (app/client/src) (client directory scructure) or on app/common (server directory structure) ?

b) If I decide to keep the files on `app/client/src/common` (server directory structure), how can I make babel_node work fine (it complains it doesn´t know environment variable)

c) If I decide to keep the files on the `app/common`, how can I access it from react components ?